# How to implement secure client-server communication over https using python and m2crypto?

Tags: encryption, ssl, server, python, client

I want to secure the communication between a server and multiple clients. 
The communication goes this way:

1. The client connects to a specific page at the server and checks for a software version.
2. If the version on client is not the latest, the client
3. connects to specific page and downloads the software update

I want to secure the 3rd part, so this connection must be over https. What I have done is to install m2crypto to the client and the server and with a python script, generate a pair of private/public keys.
The point is the server to use the client's public key to sign the data to send.

How do I configure my server (apache) so that the connection is over https?